# Nuxt JS / Vue Jest check that class name element exists on page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nuxt.js

I'm new to the Jest testing suite for Vue JS and have integrated it into my Nuxt JS application. I've set up some basic tests to check that a component is a Vue instance and these pass successfully.

I'm now trying to find an element on my page and check that it exists, and potentially the content within.

This is my structure

**pages/application/begin.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <LoanTerm />
  </div>
</template>
```

**components/Form/Steps/Loan/LoanTerm.vue**

```html
<template>
  <article>

    <article class="tw-px-7 tw-pb-7">
      <StepHeader
        title="About your loan"
        subtitle="How long do you need the money for?" />
    </article>
    <hr class="tw-mt-7" />
    <article class="tw-p-7 tw-space-y-7">

      <section>
        <validation-provider
          vvid="loan.term"
          name="Loan term"
          rules="required"
          v-slot="{ errors, classes }"
        >
          <div class="tw-grid tw-grid-cols-2 tw-gap-4">
            <label
              v-for="(term, index) in datasets.terms.slice(0, 12)"
              v-if="index % 2 == 0"
              :key="index"
              :for="`term-${index}`"
              class="tw-flex-1 tw-relative tw-bg-gray-50 tw-rounded-xl tw-p-7 tw-border-b-4 tw-border-gray-200 tw-text-center tw-cursor-pointer"
              :class="$getClasses(classes, true, fields.loan.term === term.value)">
              <input type="radio" name="term" :id="`term-${index}`" :value="term.value" v-model="fields.loan.term" class="tw-absolute tw-top-4 tw-right-4 tw-h-4 tw-w-4 focus:tw-ring-green-500 tw-text-green-600 tw-border-gray-300 jest__datasets-terms" />
              <span class="tw-block">
                {{ term.label }}
              </span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <ValidationMessage :message="errors[0]" />
        </validation-provider>
      </section>

      <section class="tw-space-y-4">
        <modal
          title="Choose address"
          :is-open="termSelectionModalIsOpen">
          <template #action-close>
            <button @click="termSelectionModalIsOpen = false" type="button" class="tw-p-3 tw-rounded-full tw-text-gray-800 tw-border tw-border-gray-300 tw-font-extrabold focus:tw-outline-none focus:tw-ring-2 focus:tw-ring-offset-2 focus:tw-ring-offset-gray-200 focus:tw-ring-white">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="tw-h-5 tw-w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
              </svg>
            </button>
          </template>
          <template #iterable-data>
            <section v-for="(term, index) in datasets.terms" :key="index">
              <button @click="chooseTerm(term)" type="button" class="tw-w-full tw-block md:hover:tw-bg-gray-50 tw-p-6 tw-text-left">
                <div class="tw-grid tw-grid-cols-3 tw-gap-6">
                  <div class="tw-col-span-2 tw-flex tw-items-center tw-text-gray-600">
                    {{ term.label }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="tw-text-right">
                    <button type="button" class="tw-p-3 tw-rounded-full tw-text-gray-800 tw-border tw-border-transparent tw-font-extrabold focus:tw-outline-none focus:tw-ring-2 focus:tw-ring-offset-2 focus:tw-ring-offset-gray-200 focus:tw-ring-white">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="tw-h-5 tw-w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 5l7 7-7 7" />
                      </svg>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </button>
              <hr />
            </section>
          </template>
        </modal>
        <button @click="termSelectionModalIsOpen = true" type="button" class="tw-py-5 tw-px-5 tw-rounded-xl tw-bg-gray-100 tw-flex tw-w-full tw-text-gray-600 tw-border tw-border-gray-200 tw-font-medium focus:tw-outline-none focus:tw-ring-2 focus:tw-ring-offset-2 focus:tw-ring-offset-gray-100 focus:tw-ring-white">
          <div class="tw-flex tw-mx-auto">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="tw-h-5 tw-w-5 tw-mr-2" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M8 7V3m8 4V3m-9 8h10M5 21h14a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z" />
            </svg>
            Choose another term
          </div>
        </button>
        <div class="md:tw-shadow-lg">
          <button type="submit" class="tw-py-5 tw-px-5 tw-rounded-xl tw-bg-green-500 md:hover:tw-bg-green-600 tw-block tw-w-full tw-text-white tw-border tw-border-gray-300 tw-font-medium focus:tw-outline-none focus:tw-ring-2 focus:tw-ring-offset-2 focus:tw-ring-offset-gray-200 focus:tw-ring-white">
            Continue
          </button>
        </div>
      </section>

    </article>

  </article>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    minTerm: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1
    },
    term: {
      type: Number,
      default: 7
    },
    maxTerm: {
      type: Number,
      default: 36
    },
    fields: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({ })
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      termSelectionModalIsOpen: false,
      datasets: {
        terms: []
      }
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.availableTerms()
  },
  methods: {

    /*
    ** Generate available terms
    */
    availableTerms () {
      for (let term = this.minTerm; term < this.maxTerm; term++) {
        this.datasets.terms.push({
          label: `${term} month${term == 1 ? '' : 's'}`,
          value: term
        })
      }
    },

    /*
    ** Choose term
    */
    chooseTerm (term = null) {
      this.fields.loan.term = term.value
      this.termSelectionModalIsOpen = false
      this.$store.commit('application/stepForwards')
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

And the test that I've got set up provides the following:

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import LoanTerm from '@/components/Form/Steps/Loan/LoanTerm'

describe('LoanTerm', () => {

  test('is a Vue instance', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(LoanTerm)
    expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy()
  })

  test('terms are available for selection', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(LoanTerm)
    const terms = await wrapper.find('.jest__datasets-terms')
    expect(terms.exists()).toBe(true)
  })

})
```

The result I get from running this test is that my "terms are available for selection
" test fails because it received **false**.

I've also tried using `findAll`, which returns nothing

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `modal`'s contents (including the "datasets-terms" buttons your test is seeking) are initially not rendered, as `termSelectionModalIsOpen` is initialized to `false`, and nothing sets it to `true`. The modal likely looks similar to this:

```html
// Modal.vue
<template>
  <div v-if="isOpen">
    <slot name="iterable-data" />
    <slot name="action-close" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    title: String,
    isOpen: false,
  }
}
</script>
```

### Solution

Mount `LoanTerm` with a `data()` property that initializes `termSelectionModalIsOpen` to `true` so that the modal's contents are rendered:

```js
const wrapper = mount(LoanTerm, {
  data () {
    return {
      termSelectionModalIsOpen: true,
    }
  },
})
```

*I noticed that `jest__datasets-terms` class is missing in `LoanTerm.vue`, but I assume that's just a copy-paste error.*

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-find-conditional-button-in-vue-test-utils?file=test%2FLoanTerm.spec.js)

Comment: thanks, but yeah, it's a copy paste error, I've put together a public repo that you can clone, and try out to see what I'm experiencing, a nested class in my provider can't be found, whereas the parent can be, maybe I'm missing one thing? See: https://github.com/sts-ryan-holton/vee-validate-nuxt-with-jest